# Create a PayPal button to accept online invoice payments

Tags: paypal

I am needing to setup a PayPal button on my client's website that will allow their customers to enter their invoice number into a text input field, click the pay button and complete the transaction on the PayPal website. What type of PayPal payment button should be used to achieve this? Would it be a standard Buy Now button or something more sophisticated?

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the [Classic Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_create-pps-buttons/). They are simple HTML buttons that pass the data to Paypal and let you pay there.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. login to your Paypal account
2. click on the Merchant Services tab
3. Under Manage Payments, click on the “Request Money with Quickbooks” link
4. Read the instructions on how to install and download the Quickbooks Payment Request wizard installation file
5. Create a Quickbooks invoice
6. Click the Payment Request Wizard button in the Quickbooks toolbar
7. Send your invoice

looking for a new online papal invoice  fetchflow.com system for your business,you are likely to find one on this list that meets all of your needs. http://www.fetchflow.com/Signup/PayPal Leverage the power of Excel to create bulk online invoices in seconds.